# Out Of Memory Exception in Maven Surefire - Jenkins - Java

Tags: java, jenkins, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm running `Testng` tests in parallel using `Maven Surefire` plugin in a Jenkins box which is a `Windows` box on `Java 1.8`. When two jobs run in parallel they run about 100 tests in parallel which the `thread-count` are all specified in `testng.xml`.

Now I migrated my `Jenkins` to an `AWS EC2 Ubuntu` based instance. The size of this box is double than what the previously mentioned `Windows` box was. However now when I run two jobs it's throwing the following exception

```
11:54:33 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
11:54:33    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
11:54:33    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
11:54:33    at com.dataprovider.CacheEngine.<init>(CacheEngine.java:47)
11:54:33    at com.core.CoreLibraries.<init>(CoreLibraries.java:81)
11:54:33    at com.dataprovider.ReadDataFile.<init>(ReadDataFile.java:39)
```

I tried the following after googling a lot

- Increased the `nproc` in `ulimit` to 500000 - Didn't work
- Increased the `xmx` and `xms` in the `surefire` plugin in `pom.xml` - Didn't work
- Tried specifying the `forkCount` to 0 and also many other numbers. Nothing worked.

My `surefire` plugin XML configuration is as follows

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xss256k -Xms1024m -Xmx4008m</argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>resources/testng/${testngFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <outputDirectory>target/test-output</outputDirectory>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <key>false</key>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
```

Comment: Sounds to me as a limit in the number of SO subprocesses (in the sense that the JVM probably starts a subprocess for each new thread). Have you searched about increasing the managed processes in Ubuntu?

Comment: Adding to what @LittleSanti said, you can also refer to this thread and see if the recommendations help : http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/how-to-solve-javalangoutofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread